# PHP Generate json file and disable cache

Tags: php, json, caching

I have a script that creates a new json file every time I upload a new version of my app.

The problem is that browsers and mobile apps seems to cache that json file.

I use `file_put_contents` to create that json file.

Is there a way to disable cache specifically for that json file when someone read it from outside?

EDIT1:
**Answer the question assuming I cannot change my clients**

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code,

Original JSON file:

```
{
  "param":"value",
  "param1" "value",
  ... etc..
}
```

JSON.PHP file

```
<?php 

$thatMuch = (60 * 60 * 24); // 24hrs
$cacheTime = (time() + $thatMuch);

$json = file_get_contents($originalJsonFile);

header('Pragma: public');
header('Cache-Control: maxage='.$thatMuch);
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $cacheTime) . ' GMT');
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo($json); 
exit;
```

If You output that JSON as it is, than file_get_contents is ok, otherwise, You do what You need to do.. use json_encode(), change last header directive to something else, etc.

Also, You could *(if You haven't done so, already) remove .php extension lookup via `.htaccess` so that .php is not needed in path, therefore, the original path/url will remain exact the same.

Something like this *(root dir .htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And this would be enough I guess...

Comment: Interesting solution. I'm gonna give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

How do You serve that file to the endusers? Are You serving that file directly? If You do, try to serve that JSON file via/by PHP as well, with proper headers before output, where `filename.json.php` will take place instead of `filename.json` or just as Paul proposed, much easier.

Comment: Directly. I grant the apps with the url on login.

Comment: If You can, try what Paul has proposed, otherwise You need to force the browsers to re-fetch file again. Create a new .json.php file, than inside that file use file_get_contents to retrieve original file, than set proper headers for caching or no caching at all and for mime/file type and output it...